# Multi-part form upload with Errai

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm trying to do a file upload for my Errai app, however I'm getting this error:

```
[INFO] DEBUG [SynchronousDispatcher] PathInfo: /blob
[INFO] WARN [ExceptionHandler] Failed executing GET /blob
[INFO] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotAcceptableException: No match for accept header
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.Segment.match(Segment.java:119)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.PathParamSegment.matchPattern(PathParamSegment.java:200)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:339)
```

The Errai service looks like this:

```
@Path("blob")
public interface BlobService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    String getBlobStoreUploadUrl(); // return "/blob/upload"

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    Picture getPicture(@PathParam("id") String id);

    @POST 
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    void uploadPicture();
}
```

Now, upload is triggered this way:

```
submitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
                blobService.call(new RemoteCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void callback(String response) {
                        uploadForm.setAction(response);
                        uploadForm.submit();
                        uploadForm.reset();
                    }
                }).getBlobStoreUploadUrl();
            }
        });
```

From what it seems there a discrepancy on how I did file upload. The idea here is just to upload the file selected in the usual upload form to the `uploadPicture` method.

What could be wrong in the way I coded the upload service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set the mime type on the form? like so

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the Guice binding of the BlobService